# JS: ScrollTo not moving element

Tags: javascript

I am building a carousel in vanilla JS and I have a two arrows (pointers) in which I am using event delegation and have a listener on the parent.  I am checking if the target class contains `left` or `right` and then appropriately handling it.  I am taking the `carousel-images` element, which has *all* the images on it side by side with a width and hiding them using `overflow: hidden`.  Depending which arrow I click, I grab that `carousel-images` element and use `scrollLeft` and subtract/add the child image's clientWidth.  I had it working a while ago but now it seems to not have any effect and i am not sure where I went wrong.

https://jsfiddle.net/zye01vcn/1/

***html***

```
<div>
    <div class="carousel-container">
      <div class="carousel-images">
        <div class="carousel-image">

        </div>
        <div class="carousel-image two">

        </div>
        <div class="carousel-image three">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pointers"> 
        <span class="left">
          <
        </span>
        <span class="right">
          >
        </span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***js***

```
(function (doc) {
    //
    // Methods
    //
    function arrowClick(evt) {
        if (evt.target.classList.contains('left')) {
            carouselImagesContainer.scrollLeft -= carouselImages[0].clientWidth;
        } else if (evt.target.classList.contains('right')) {
            carouselImagesContainer.scrollLeft += carouselImages[0].clientWidth;
        }
    }


    let testImages = ['https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/cat.png', 'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/boat.png', 'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png'];
    let carouselImagesContainer = document.querySelector('.carousel-images');
    let carouselImages = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-image');
    let pointers = document.querySelector('.pointers');

    carouselImages.forEach((x,i) => {
        let el = document.createElement('img');
        el.src = testImages[i];
        x.appendChild(el);
    })
    pointers.addEventListener('click', arrowClick);

})(document);
```

***css***

```
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .carousel-container {
        height: 100vh;
        background:blue;
        width: calc(100% - 20px);
        margin: 0 auto;
        overflow: hidden;

    }
    .carousel-images {
        display: flex;
        width: 10000px;
    }
    .carousel-image {
        width: calc(100% - 40px);
        background: green;
        height: 100vh;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    .two {
        background-color: pink;
    }
    .three {
        background-color: red;
    }
  span {
    font-size: 90px
  }
    .pointers {
        background: transparent;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 22222222;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't work is because

```
let carouselImagesContainer = document.querySelector('.carousel-images');
```

should be

```
let carouselImagesContainer = document.querySelector('.carousel-container');
```

You were getting the .carousel-images and not the .carousel-container.

You also need to change the following because this is malformed:

```
    <span class="left">
      <
    </span>
    <span class="right">
      >
    </span>
```

To:

```
    <span class="left">
      &lt;
    </span>
    <span class="right">
      &gt;
    </span>
```

Comment: hmm that works, thank you.... I can't understand why I'd be "scrolling" on that though since `.carousel-images` is the element that has a width of 1000px, not `.carousel-container`.

Comment: It is because you have overflow:hidden in the css. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft the part about overflow

Answer (score 0):

Change the style of the '.carousel-images' selector to the following:

```
.carousel-images {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

The 'overflow-x: scroll;' is essential. The 'width' property you can change, but it needs to be less than the combined width of its '.carousel-image' children in order for the scrolling to work (otherwise there is no need for scrolling, the content is simply hidden).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.carousel-images {
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}
img{
 width:100%
 }
.carousel-image {
 flex: 0 0 100%;
 background: green;
 height: 100vh;
 padding: 20px;
}
```